# Laravel Many to Many relation ship \ USERS -ROLES

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I want to get all users:

```
$users=User::get();
```

After that I want the name for every role.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
   return $user->roles->name;
}
```

But it gives an error  `Trying to get property of non-object`

Any idea how to get name for all users and roles?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access single item from many to many relationship:

> As a User has Many roles, you should first iterate over its each role
>   and get the role name, or simple take out the first object from the Collection.

Just use [`first()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_first):

```
$users = User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
   return $user->roles->first()->name;
}
```

Or if you want to get each one:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
   foreach($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->name;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's the same with all :)

Comment: @NikolaVi - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: I voted for you and it said thank for feedback but doesn't increments number of votes  !!

Comment: @NikolaVi you need to have at least 15 reputation for voting ;)

Comment: Yup, that's true! and what about for accepting the asnwers? :D

Answer (score 0):

`$user->roles` is a collection, you need to do one more foreach :

`foreach($user->roles as $role) 
   return $role->name`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();

$usersRolesNames = $users->roles->lists('name');
```